# Can we access simple data of discord without a bot token

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a strange question I am making an app html app(using [electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron))but I need a part that shows a users avatar without token(because I'm gonna make app downloadable so if I put it in env it still gonna be seen(this is what I know but if it's wrong please write it in answer I don't know that much on envs))

Comment: Firstly, I don't know too much about discordjs. But I think that you need a backend server for it (you need an api server). You can execute your discortjs commands in backend and return specific responses that you wanted. Like I said, I don't know too much about discordjs but if you keep your token in backend server it will be secure app.

Comment: The token being on a separate (refrenced) file inside the app will keep the token secure. Since the app will have to connect to your server to run, it will have access to those files but they won't be included in the downloaded section unless you put it there or make the app standalone. But to answer your question, without a token, you can't access a members url unless you hardcode the avatar url for each member and then update it everytime someone leaves or joins.

Comment: thank you both I got the answer that I needed

Comment: You need a token to make API requests

Answer (score 0):

You can show a users avatar if they're authenticated to your app. That can be accomplished using Discord's OAUTH2 API. You can read more on how to implement it [here](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/). Depending on which scopes you choose, some data may be available or not. In this case, you'll need the `identify` scope to get access to the users data (avatar, username, discriminator).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).